# Barcode parsing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, barcode

For example I have this form:

As you can see I have Barcode textbox, and 6 more textboxes. What I need is a code that will parse my barcode from the textbox and fill in the remaining fields. The parenthesis ie `()`, and the numbers inside it, have to be deleted.

[image: LINK TO IMAGE]

Here is example of my barcode

```
(1)CODE1(3)NAME(4)SURNAME(8)CODE2(10)CODE3(12)CODE4
```

For now I have this code:

```
Private Sub Barcode_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Barcode.Leave
    Dim Duzina As String = Me.Barcode.Text.Length
    Dim I As Integer = 0
    Dim Slog As String = ""
    Dim Rec As String = Me.Barcode.Text
    For I = 4 To Duzina
        If Rec.Substring(I, 1) = "(" Then
            Me.Surname.Text = Slog
            Exit For
        End If
        Slog = Slog + Rec.Substring(I, 0)
    Next

End Sub
```

So when the barcode loads into the first textbox, it should fill up all the other textboxes.

Comment: If you are comfortable learning Regular Expressions, here's a starting point "\([0-9]+\)([A-z0-9]+)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in this way

```
Private Function CitanjeBarkoda() As Boolean
    Dim Duzina As String = Me.TextBox8.Text.Length
    Dim I As Integer = 0
    Dim Slog As String = ""
    Dim Rec As String = Me.TextBox8.Text
    Dim BrOz As Integer = 0
    Dim BrZz As Integer = 0
    Dim NizOz As New ArrayList
    Dim NizZz As New ArrayList
    Dim Slog1 As String = ""


    For I = 0 To Duzina - 1
        If Rec.Substring(I, 1) = "(" Then
            BrOz = BrOz + 1
            NizOz.Add(I)
        End If
        If Rec.Substring(I, 1) = ")" Then
            BrZz = BrZz + 1
            NizZz.Add(I)
        End If



    Next
    Me.TextBox10.Text = Rec.Substring(NizZz(0) + 1, NizOz(1) - NizZz(0) - 1)
    Me.IMEOSOBE = Rec.Substring(NizZz(1) + 1, NizOz(2) - NizZz(1) - 1)
    Me.PREZIMEOSOBE = Rec.Substring(NizZz(2) + 1, NizOz(3) - NizZz(2) - 1)
    Me.TextBox3.Text = Rec.Substring(NizZz(3) + 1, NizOz(4) - NizZz(3) - 1)
    Me.BRKART = Rec.Substring(NizZz(4) + 1, NizOz(5) - NizZz(4) - 1)
    Me.TextBox5.Text = Rec.Substring(NizZz(5) + 1, NizOz(6) - NizZz(5) - 1)
return true
End function
```

Answer (score 2):

My simple solution

```
Private Sub Barcode_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Barcode.Leave
    Dim codes = barcodeTextBox.Text.Split("("c)
    Dim code1 = codes(1).Split(")"c)
    Dim name = codes(2).Split(")"c)
    Dim surename = codes(3).Split(")"c)
    Dim code2 = codes(4).Split(")"c)
    Dim code3 = codes(5).Split(")"c)
    Dim code4 = codes(6).Split(")"c)

    sureNameTextBox.Text = surename(0).ToString()
    nameTextBox.Text = name(0).ToString()
    code1TextBox.Text = code1(0).ToString()
    code2TextBox.Text = code2(0).ToString()
    code3TextBox.Text = code3(0).ToString()
    code4TextBox.Text = code4(0).ToString()
End Sub
```

Alternative solution

```
Private Sub Barcode_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Barcode.Leave
    Dim codes = barcodeTextBox.Text.Split("("c)
    Dim code1 = codes(1).Split(")"c).FirstOrDefault()
    Dim name = codes(2).Split(")"c).FirstOrDefault()
    Dim surename = codes(3).Split(")"c).FirstOrDefault()
    Dim code2 = codes(4).Split(")"c).FirstOrDefault()
    Dim code3 = codes(5).Split(")"c).FirstOrDefault()
    Dim code4 = codes(6).Split(")"c).FirstOrDefault()

    sureNameTextBox.Text = surename
    nameTextBox.Text = name
    code1TextBox.Text = code1
    code2TextBox.Text = code2
    code3TextBox.Text = code3
    code4TextBox.Text = code4
End Sub
```

Comment: @kenny, what do you mean sir? :)

Comment: as an example should it be sureNameTextBox.Text = surename(1).ToString()    and the rest similar

Comment: okay sir, I `split` the `surename` so the [0] index is a _number_ which is need to place into `sureNameTextBox`.

Comment: OK, I thought the OP asked that the number in the () are to be deleted, but maybe I'm reading it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the title is a little misleading. It should be string parsing and not barcode parsing. Anyway, you can try this.

```
Private Sub Barcode_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Barcode.Leave
    Dim pvsBarcodeRAW As String = Trim(Me.Barcode.Text.Length)
    Dim voNVC As New System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection

    Dim vasCodePairs() As String = Split(pvsBarcodeRAW, "(")
    For Each vsCodePair As String In vasCodePairs
        vsCodePair = Trim(vsCodePair)
        If vsCodePair.Length > 0 Then
            Dim vasCodePair() As String = Split(vsCodePair, ")")
            If vasCodePair.Length = 2 Then
                Select Case vasCodePair(0)
                    Case 1
                        voNVC("Code1") = vasCodePair(1)
                    Case 3
                        voNVC("Name") = vasCodePair(1)
                    Case 4
                        voNVC("SurName") = vasCodePair(1)
                    Case 8
                        voNVC("Code2") = vasCodePair(1)
                    Case 10
                        voNVC("Code3") = vasCodePair(1)
                    Case 12
                        voNVC("Code4") = vasCodePair(1)
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Now you can do whatever you want with the variables in the voNVC variable.
    SurName.Text = voNVC("SurName")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `$I` in a Code 39 barcode with keymapping enabled on the scanner.  `$I` will act like a TAB key on the keyboard.

One scan of

```
CODE1$INAME$ISURNAME$ICODE2$ICODE3$ICODE4
```

Will populate this:
CODE1
NAME
SURNAME
CODE2
CODE3
CODE4

With that said, Code 39 is not good for long barcodes.  You could use QR, but tabs are a bit more complex there, still doable though. You would also need a 2D scanner.